# Prove $(X \Delta Y\subseteq B \land Y \Delta Z\subseteq B) \to (X \Delta Z\subseteq B)$: is it legit to combine proof by cases and indirect proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove $(X \Delta Y\subseteq B \land Y \Delta Z\subseteq B) \to (X \Delta Z\subseteq B)$, where $X \Delta Y$ means $(X \setminus Y)\cup (Y\setminus X)$.

Take $s$ as an arbitrary element, then I am allowed to assume $s \in X\setminus Z \lor s \in Z\setminus X$ to prove $s\in B$.

My question is, is it legit to combine both  indirect proof and proof by cases? i.e. Firstly assume $s\notin B$, then assume $s \in X\setminus Z$ and $s \in Z\setminus X$ in turn to derive a contradiction?

Since if both components of a disjunction imply a contradiction, then surely that means no matter which disjunct is true, $\lnot (s\in B)$ is problematic and thus it cannot be true?  (I tried and eventually derived a contradiction from assuming either of the disjuncts)

I tried to verify this by proving $\lnot (s \in X\setminus Z)$, and then deriving a contradiction from there; and that works. But I am not sure if this means combining both methods is mathematically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is legitimate. You can combine those proof methods as detailed.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any thing I should be careful about when using more than one proof method at the same time? Because I don't think I have seen anyone using two before and hence I am feeling very insecure about this

Comment: All I can offer there is vague advice. Try to be careful about where one method ends and another begins. Be sure to know what you're doing and why.